# Accessing index of array returned by __get() magic method

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to use the magic method `__get()` with a class in order to access a private property. The property is not assigned a value unless it is accessed, and that value is an array which is indexed from 0.

```
class Foo {
    private $bar;

    public function __get($p) {
        if ($p == 'bar') {
            if ($this->bar) {
                return $this->bar;
            }
            else {
                return $this->bar = $this->get_bar();
            }
        }
    }

    private function get_bar() {
        return Array('a', 'b', 'c');    // data from db
    }
}
```

In my PHP code, I am instantiating an object of this class, and passing it directly to Smarty (i.e. `$smarty->assign('obj', new Foo())`). I would like to access the value at index 0 from the `$bar` property within my template file. I have tried this:

```
    {$obj->bar[0]}
```

However, this is not returning anything for me... Is this something that is not supported by the data returned by this magic method?

Comment: `if ($bar) {` should probably be `if ($this->bar) {`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I was typing out a model for what I am trying, that is, in fact, present in my actual code. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: And you should still be able to access the values under the array directly. `$f = new Foo(); echo $f->bar[0];` should still output 'a'.

Comment: Then is this a limitation of Smarty, perhaps?

Comment: Are you trying to access this value in your template? If you are, Smarty `assign()` only accepts name value pairs or associative arrays--no objects.

Comment: I am fairly certain that you can assign objects to Smarty, as well access methods and properties from template files: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.tpl#language.variables.objects In this case, I am assigning with name/value pair, object is value.

Comment: @djentastic See my answer, I hope it helps. You need to use a separate method for object assignments. Cleverly enough, they did not include it on the page you linked... [Correct Page](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/advanced.features.tpl)

Comment: @djentastic please don't edit answers into the question. Instead, post the answer as an answer.

Comment: @Ren as I explained, I was not able to answer my own question at the time. Posting again now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry everyone!

My problem was that, in the actual code, I was trying to access an array element which was actually embedded in an array one level deeper.

I was going to delete this question, however I feel as though it will be a good reference to demonstrate that an array returned by a magic method in this manner can be accessed with the standard subscript operator, even within a Smarty template.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$smarty->assign()` to assign objects, `assign()` only accepts associative arrays and name value pairs. Use [`assign_by_ref()`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/advanced.features.tpl) instead to send objects to your template.

**PHP/Smarty Example**

```
$foo = new Foo();
$smarty->assign_by_ref('obj', $foo);
```

**Template Example/Useage**

```
{$obj->bar[0]}
```

Comment: Again, I do not believe this is the solution. In the link you provided above, it actually states `The other way is to assign() objects to the templates and access them much like any other assigned variable` However, I fear that I have posed a question for a problem which was caused by my own mistake in code. Thanks for the effort, though.